# Do we need to submit our Application in App Store to Test In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I implemented In-App purchases in my project but I'm not getting Product Id.I haven't submitted my application to App Store.Means after adding in-app purchase it is showing Ready to Submit in in-app purchase column and showing Prepare for Submission in iOS App column.So can I test my In-App purchase now ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes you can test...